# How to mutate first value of a vector for each group of a grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have accomplished this in a hacky way through the following code

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
    slice(1:3) %>% 
    arrange(cyl, mpg) %>% 
    mutate(mpg = ifelse( seq_along(mpg) == 1, 0, mpg ))
```

But I feel there is a better way to do this.

Comment: you can use `row_number() == 1` instead of `seq_along()`. Other than that, this looks okay.

Comment: I think the last step can be condensed to `mtcars %>% select(cyl, mpg) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% slice(1:3) %>% mutate(mpg = (row_number(mpg) != 1) * mpg)`

Comment: Or `replace` maybe `mutate(mpg = replace(mpg,1,0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are okay to wrap with `head/sort`, this can be done in less number of steps.  After grouping by 'cyl', get the first 3 elements of 'mpg' with `head`, `sort` it, remove the first element (`[-1]`), concatenate (`c`) with 0, wrap it in a `list` within `summarise` and then `unnest` the `list`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(mpg = list(c(0, sort(head(mpg, 3))[-1]))) %>%
    unnest
```

Comment: interesting. To be clear, I only limited to the first 3 observations for brevity. But overall your solution is perfect.

Comment: @Joe You can do this for any number of rows. `head(mpg, n)`